# Making two calls in same function

Tags: javascript, react-native, fetch-api

I have two requests a GET and a POST request, I'm fetching the GET request and setting the response state inside and array and I want to pass this array to the POST request body, then I'm fetching the POST request so I can make the call, the problem is that it's not setting the state in the GET call and it's always returning undefined and i can't figure out why, here is the code:

**My constructor:**

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    info: [],
  }
}
```

**Function:**

```
myFunction = async () => {
  fetch("https://myapp.com/info", {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "x-auth-token": token
    }
  })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(response => {
      this.setState({ info: response });
      fetch("https://myapp.com/submit_info", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "x-auth-token": token
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          infoID: this.state.info.id
        })
      })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(result => {
          console.log(result);
        });
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
};
```

Comment: React's [`setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) calls are also asynchronous.  You should just use the array result from the `GET` request as the input to your `POST` request.  I don't see a compelling need to first save it to state before the next request.

Comment: Have a look at the documentation for setState in React. It is async, so requires a callback like `this.setState({ info: response}, () => { ...second fetch here })`

Answer (score 2):

you forgot to return the promise, then use the `response` object to set the `infoID` field and not the state cause the call to `this.setState` is asynchronous and will still be pending when you make the second api call.

```
myFunction = () => {
  fetch("https://myapp.com/info", {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "x-auth-token": token
    }
  })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(response => {
      this.setState({ info: response }); // async call
      return fetch("https://myapp.com/submit_info", {
        // return promise for chaining
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "x-auth-token": token
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          infoID: response.id
        })
      })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(result => {
          console.log(result);
        });
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
};
```

Comment: You should add a note that setting react state here has no impact on the second request.

Comment: yes that's i why i've suggested to use the response object of the first api call rather then the state.